# next statement in function to go next in loop where function is used

Tags: r, function, loops, error-handling

I made a function to handle errors when webscraping:

```
get_page <- function(url, user_agent = "my information", skipped) {
  
  headers <- add_headers(`User-Agent` = user_agent)
  
  if (!exists(skipped, envir = .GlobalEnv)) {
    assign(skipped, c(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
  
  for (attempt in 1:4) {
    response <- GET(url, headers = headers)
    http_code <- response$status_code
    
    if (http_code == 200) {
      page <- read_html(rawToChar(response$content))
      return(page)
    } else if (http_code %in% c(400, 401, 403, 404)) {
      cat("HTTP", http_code, "error for", url, "\n")
      assign(skipped, c(get(skipped), url), envir = .GlobalEnv)
      return(NULL)
    }
    
    print(http_code)
    
    if (attempt == 4) {
      cat("Skipped", url, "\n")
      assign(skipped, c(get(skipped), url), envir = .GlobalEnv)
      return(NULL)
    }
    
    Sys.sleep(30)
  }
}
```

Currently, if it returns error codes 400-404 or if it fails 3 times, I handle this by checking if page is NULL after I use the function:

```
for (url in urls){ 
  page <- get_page(url, skipped = "skipped_pers_aau")
  
  if (is.null(page)) {
    next
  }

  #...here comes the parsing and storing part
```

However, this means that i have to include the `if (is.null(page))`-part after everytime I call the `get_page` function. It would be better if the function was able to go to the next url in the urls itself, however, to my knowledge, if i use `next` within a function, this won't go to the next part of the loop where the function is used inside.

Are there any way I can modify the function, so I could just do the webscraping and error handling with:

```
for (url in urls){ 
  page <- get_page(url, skipped = "skipped_pers_aau")
  
  #...here comes the parsing and storing part
```

...i.e., let the function know that it should go to the next part of the loop where the function is used inside (not having to include the `if (is.null(page))`-part or anything else, but simple just define page using the function, and then this alone would handle the errors)?

Comment: Nope, the function does not get to control (directly) how the _caller_ handles its return. What's so onerous about `if (is.null(page)) next`?

Comment: ... Or just get the parsing and storing function (you've written that as a function, right?) to start with `if (is.null(page)) return # Nothing to do`....

Comment: @r2evans not exactly onerous, but my intention with defining functions is to make things as easy as possible, therefore i am curious if there was a way to skip the 'if (is.null...'-part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @r2evans said in the comments, you cannot pass `next` from a function. However, you can refactor. As well as your function returning `NULL`, have it return an error. We can use [`tryCatch()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) to make the loop continue after the error.

I am just going to use toy functions to demonstrate the concept. The `urls` will be `c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")`, and `"c"` will return an error:

```r
get_page <- function(url) {
    if (url == "c") stop("Error") else url
}
```

We can also create a `parse_page()` function which returns `NULL` if it is supplied a `page` which caused an error.

```r
parse_page <- function(page) {
    if (is.null(page)) {
        return(NULL)
    }
    # Do the parsing here but in this
    # case we'll return the whole page
    page
}
```

Technically this does not require you to raise an error, as it just checks for `NULL` (which `stop()` returns), but I think it's better to do raise an error (or at least a warning) if you plan to use this function in other places.

Then your loop might look something like:

```r
urls <- letters[1:5]
page_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(urls)) |>
    setNames(urls)
for (url in urls) {
    page <- tryCatch(get_page(url), error = \(e) message(e, "\n"))

    page_list[[url]] <- parse_page(page)
}
```

This will print your error message but it will keep going. Your `page_list` object will be:

```r
page_list
# $a
# [1] "a"

# $b
# [1] "b"

# $d
# [1] "d"

# $e
# [1] "e"
```